# Sending an audio file over TCP using sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, audio, wav

Sending a normal .txt file works perfectly fine. But if I try to send a .wav file, the output file that gets generated is only a fraction of the size of the input file (and it doesn't play anything). I've tried pretty much everything I could find on Google, it might have something to do with not reading the .wav file correctly. But I'm reading and writing one character at a time, so I don't know why that should be a problem. Also, doing this over localhost. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

**server.c**

```
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 32

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, n;
     socklen_t clilen, servlen;

     char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
     FILE *fp;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");

     listen(sockfd, 5);

     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     servlen = sizeof(serv_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");

     bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
     n = read(newsockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

     printf("Received file name: %s\n", buffer);

     fp = fopen(buffer, "rb"); 
     if (fp == NULL) 
         printf("File open failed!\n"); 
     else
         printf("File successfully opened!\n");

    while (1) {
        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        char ch;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) { 
            ch = fgetc(fp); 
            buffer[i] = ch; 
            if (ch == EOF) 
                break; 
        }
        n = write(newsockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (n < 0) 
            error("ERROR writing to socket");

        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
    }
    printf("File sending complete...\n");

    if (fp != NULL)  
        fclose(fp);
     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);

     return 0; 
}
```

**client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

#define BUFFER_SIZE 32

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    FILE *out;
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }

    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

    printf("Enter the file name: ");
    bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, stdin);
    buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';

    n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");

    out = fopen("out.wav", "wb");
    while (1) {
        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        int i, j;

        n = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (n < 0) 
            error("ERROR reading from socket");

        char ch; 
        for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
            ch = buffer[i];  
            if (ch == EOF) 
                break; 
            j = (int)ch;
            fputc(j, out);
        }
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
    }
    printf("File write complete... You can now use the output file!!\n");

    if (out != NULL)  
        fclose(out);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ch = buffer[i]; if (ch == EOF)` That doesn't look right. `read` will never store `EOF` into the buffer. In fact it can't as `EOF` is an `int` not a `char`.

Comment: `char ch; ch = fgetc(fp); if (ch == EOF)` Similarly, that is also wrong. `fgetc` returns an `int`. That's important as `EOF` is an `int`.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)`. That is also wrong. You are assuming every `read` will receive the full `BUFFER_SIZE`. That is a common misunderstanding. For stream based protocols like TCP each read may receive a variable number of bytes. Need to use the return value of `read` rather than just assume `BUFFER_SIZE`. As it is, you are likely writing unintended zeros into the file.

Comment: @kaylum I mean, you might be right. But I just tried to print inside that if statement to see if it ever matches something (ch == EOF ever gets true), and it does indeed. Also, if that was a problem, shouldn't sending .txt files also not work? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't mean that the `EOF` was **the** problem. Just pointing out it is **a** problem. Also, you shouldn't make the argument "it seemed to work so must be ok". You need to code based on API definitions and an understanding of what is right and what is wrong. It may "work" today but bugs like this can cause failures at any time. Anyway, my third comment is a more likely candidate for your specific issue.

Comment: @kaylum haha, just trying to figure things out man. Apologies if it came off rude. No need to be patronizing :)

Comment: And I apologise if it came across as patronising. One doesn't know the expertise level of the person on the other side of the keyboard. After being on SO for a while you do see many people that are still learning the basics and pointing out even simple things often helps them. Many people really do think that passing one test means their code is bug free (they even say that explicitly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the end-of-transmission, you have to check the return value of read(), rather than checking for EOF in the read data.
I have also taken the liberty to restructure and simplify your code.

Consider the following (untested) changes:

server.c:

```
// ...
while (1) {
    size_t num_read = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
    if (num_read == 0) // end of file.
        break;
         

    n = write(newsockfd, buffer, num_read);
    if (n < 0) // Error
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    else if (n == 0) // Could handle this too
        break;
}
// ...
```

client.c:

```
// ...
while (1) {
    n = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
    else if (n == 0) // Socket closed. Transfer is complete (or borked)
        break;

    fwrite(buffer, 1, n, out); // Could check fwrite too.
}
// ...
```

Comment: Tried it out, the code looks much, much more simpler now and the problem seems to have been fixed. Thanks a bunch!